# Enable/Disable radio buttons on selection of another radio button

Tags: jquery, sql-server, html, asp.net-mvc-4

```
Radio buttons
Groups
{

        <div>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groups, "Parts", new { id = "Parts",@class="groupsRadio", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })<span>Parts</span>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groups, "Labor", new { id = "Labor",@class="groupsRadio", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })<span>Labor</span>                     
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groups, "Tax", new { id = "Tax",@class="groupsRadio", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })<span>Tax</span>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groups, "Other", new { id = "Other",@class="groupsRadio", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })<span>Other</span>       
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.groups) 
        </div>
    }


   Radio Buttons Group Type
    {
      <div>

             @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "None", new { id = "None", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })<span>None</span>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "Labor", new { id = "Labor", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })<span>Labor</span>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "Refinishing", new { id = "Refinishing", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })<span>Refinishing</span>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "Sublet", new { id = "Sublet", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })<span>Sublet</span>                     
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.groupType, "Miscellaneous", new { id = "Miscellaneous", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })<span>Miscellaneous</span>

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.groupType) 
        </div>
    }
```

Now

1.On selection of radio button 'Other' i have to disable Radio button groups Type 'Labor' and 'Refinishing'

1. On selection of 'Tax' enable only 'None'
2. On selection of 'Labor' disable 'Sublet' and 'Miscellaneous'
3. On selection of 'parts' enable only 'None'

please help to write jQuery for this.. i am beginner 
Thanks in advance

Comment: we will surely help u but what have u tried?

Comment: You should have googled it first..

Comment: do like this: $('#Other').click(function(){ $('#Labor,#Refinishing').prop('disabled',true); })

Comment: @SomnathKharat i tried this {<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.groupsRadio').change(function () {
        var selectedRadio = $('.groupsRadio'.checked).val();
        if (selectedRadio == 'Other') {
            $('#Labor').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#Refinishing').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $('#Labor').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#Refinishing').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
</script>}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get you started....

```
$("#Other").click(function(){
    $('#Labor,#Refinishing').prop('disabled',true);
});
$("#Parts,#Labor,#Tax").click(function(){
    $('#Labor,#Refinishing').prop('disabled',false);
});
$("#Tax").click(function(){
    $('#None').prop('disabled',false);
    $('#Labor,#Refinishing,#Sublet,#Miscellaneous').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Similary you could do for the rest of your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Yaseer your code helped me.. its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-display_id attribute` like,

```
<div>
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(..., new {data-display_id='#None', id = "Parts",... })<span>Parts</span>
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(..., new {data-display_id='#Sublet,#Miscellaneous', id = "Labor",... })<span>Labor</span>                     
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(..., new {data-display_id='#None', id = "Tax",....})<span>Tax</span>
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(..., new {data-display_id='#Labor,#Refinishing', id = "Other"... })<span>Other</span>       
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.groups) 
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('[type="radio"][data-display_id]').click(function(){
    $($(this).data('display_id')).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: what is display_id?? and how can u put string between character literal

Comment: See this line `@Html.RadioButtonFor(..., new {data-display_id='#None'`. display_id is `custom data attribute`